# Making poker game with Set of tuple

Tags: python-3.x

First I have `Hands = Set[Tuple[str,str]]` to represents the suits and ranks of the card respectively( `Hands = {("Diamonds", "4"),("Clubs","J"),...}`). then I have to check if `Hands` contain straight flush combination(All 5 cards have the same suit in sequence.) I tried using for loop to check if all the cards have same suits but the problem is that I can't slice the element inside set. After that I am stumped. Is there a way to return a boolean that indicate whether variable `Hands` is straight flush?

Here is my code I have been working on

```
Hands = Set[Tuple[str,str]]
h = {("Diamonds", "Q"),("Diamonds","J"),("Diamonds","K"),("Diamonds","A"),("Diamonds","2")}

def is_sflush(h:Hands) -> bool:
    for i in h:
    if h[i][0] == h[i+1][0]: #This is where I am wrong and need help here
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a H/W problem, so not to give away the farm...

you have 2 checks to figure out:  same suit and sequential.  Do them separately.

For the "same suit", I recommend making a `set` of the *suits* from the cards (not the ranks), which you can do from a set comprehension.  What will the size of that set tell you?

The sequential part is a bit more work.  :)  You might need an extra data structure that has the correct sequencing or position of the cards as something to compare against.  Several strategies could work.